# Find non overlapping times

Tags: prolog, schedule

I'm given a serie of university subjects with their lessons time and I have to find all non overlapping subjects to make a schedule.

This is what I have so far

```
%% lesson(+Day: atom, +Begin: time, +End: time)
%% course(+Class: string, +Lessons: list)
%% subject(+Name: string, +Course: course)
% some test subjects that are going to match since they doesn't overlap
subject('SRE', course('3K2', [lesson(mon ,time(08, 00, 0), time(10, 25, 0))])).
subject('PAV', course('4K5', [lesson(mon, time(14, 55, 0), time(18, 05, 0)), lesson(thu, time(14, 55, 0), time(18, 05, 0))])).
subject('DSI', course('3K2', [lesson(tue, time(08, 00, 0), time(10, 25, 0)), lesson(wed, time(08, 00, 0), time(10, 25, 0))])).
subject('COM', course('3K2', [lesson(tue, time(10, 25, 0), time(12, 05, 0)), lesson(fri, time(11, 20, 0), time(12, 50, 0))])).
subject('TSB', course('3K3', [lesson(tue, time(14, 55, 0), time(18, 05, 0)), lesson(fri, time(14, 55, 0), time(18, 05, 0))])).
subject('TCO', course('4K3', [lesson(tue, time(19, 55, 0), time(23, 05, 0)), lesson(fri, time(19, 55, 0), time(21, 25, 0))])).
subject('PYE', course('2K4', [lesson(thu, time(08, 00, 0), time(10, 25, 0)), lesson(fri, time(08, 00, 0), time(10, 25, 0))])).
subject('LEG', course('3R3', [lesson(thu, time(18, 15, 0), time(19, 45, 0))])).


%% overlaps(-T1: list, -T2: list)
% don't know if it should be solved with something like this
overlaps(T1, T2) :-
  pass.


%% scheduler(+Subjects: list)
scheduler(Subjects) :-
  findall(Subjects,
          ( subject(Name, course(Class, Lessons)),
            overlaps(Lessons) )),
  pass.
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important things to know about Prolog is that it forces you to break down your solution to a problem into *very* small pieces. This can be annoying, because sometimes dealing with tiny details first can feel like you're not getting closer to your solution. But it's also good news: Once you're used to decomposing your program into small, understandable, self-contained, independently testable pieces, it will make you a better programmer forever, in any programming language.

I won't give you a complete solution to your homework problem, but I'll help you get started with the structure. You have correctly identified that you need some notion of "overlapping" of two lessons. But you need more: Lessons overlap if their start or end times are in some specific relation. So the first thing to do is to define a relation on times.

Write a predicate `time_before/2` so that `time_before(TimeA, TimeB)` is true if `TimeA` is before `TimeB`. It should behave like this, for example:

```
?- time_before(time(09, 00, 00), time(10, 30, 00)).
true .

?- time_before(time(10, 30, 00), time(09, 00, 00)).
false.

?- time_before(time(09, 45, 00), time(10, 15, 00)).
true .

?- time_before(time(10, 15, 00), time(09, 45, 00)).
false.
```

You will probably need several clauses of the form

```
time_before(time(HA, MA, SA), time(HB, MB, SB)) :-
    ...
```

Based on this, you can write a predicate expressing that two lessons overlap:

```
?- lesson_overlapping(lesson(mon, time(09, 15, 00), time(10, 45, 00)), lesson(mon, time(10, 00, 00), time(11, 00, 00))).
true .

?- lesson_overlapping(lesson(mon, time(09, 00, 00), time(09, 45, 00)), lesson(mon, time(10, 00, 00), time(11, 00, 00))).
false.
```

or that two lessons do *not* overlap:

```
?- lesson_nonoverlapping(lesson(mon, time(09, 15, 00), time(10, 45, 00)), lesson(mon, time(10, 00, 00), time(11, 00, 00))).
false.

?- lesson_nonoverlapping(lesson(mon, time(09, 00, 00), time(09, 45, 00)), lesson(mon, time(10, 00, 00), time(11, 00, 00))).
true .
```

If you have already learned about negation, you could write any one of these and then use it to define the other. You can (and should) also write both of them more directly, but for one of them you will need to be able to express that two days differ.

Based on this you can then write a predicate for expressing that all lessons in a list are non-overlapping. But for this, too, it is first useful to write an independently testable predicate like

```
lesson_nonoverlappings(Lesson, Lessons)
```

expressing that the given `Lesson` does not overlap with any element of the `Lessons` list.

Overall this should help you solve your problem by taking small steps at a time. Good luck, and do open new questions when you get stuck with any of the specific parts!